# Using GCP service discovery when Prometheus is running on GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, prometheus, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-networking

I am setting up Prometheus on GKE. I have some VMs external to the GKE cluster running node exporter that I wish to also retrieve machine metrics.

I setup gce_sd_configs in Prometheus and it finds out about the existance external VMs. However, it cannot retrieve the metrics from those VMs as access from the pod running prometheus to those VMs appears to be blocked.

I have attempted to setup some firewall rules. All my research so far talks about creating a "headless service" to access services outside of the Kubernetes cluster. However, this doesn't feel scalable to do if I want to monitor metrics for all my VMs running outside of Kubernetes.

Has anyone experience with running this setup?

Comment: gce_sd_configs is correct. You just need to adjust your VPC firewall rules so that the VMs allow access to the metrics port, for the IP address of Prometheus. Since prometheus runs in a pod inside GKE, it will have a different subnet. Headless service is unnecessary.

Comment: Ok thank you! I wasn't sure how to figure out the firewall rules specifically, so to test I just created a similar VM to one my GKE VMs to test and that worked. So just need to get a better understanding of firewall setup in order to reproduce!

Comment: Just to inform you, this question is on topic in this forum but it may be better served on Google groups. [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/) is a dedicated discussion forum for Google Cloud Platform & is made for more general, design type questions.